# How to inherit ViewModel class to UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

Suppose that I've a `ViewModel` class with different property such as:

```
//MainVm will inherit ViewModel that contains IPropertyChanged implementation
public class MainVM : ViewModel 
{
     publi bool Foo { get; set; } 
}
```

I instatiated this class on the main `controller` in this way:

```
MainController mc;

public MaiWindow()
{
    mc = new MainController(); 
    DataContext = mc;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

the `MainController` have this implementation:

```
public class MainController : MainVM 
{
    some methods
}
```

so each time I need to access to a property of MainController on each `UserControls` I need to do: `Application.Current.MainWindow.mc.Foo`

and this is't elegant at all.

Is possible access to the property of specific ViewModel without call the code line above?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

For add more details and clarification to this question: so in my UserControl I need to access to the `Foo` property that is part of `MainVM`. I'm spoke about the `UserControl` xaml code (not the controller of the UserControl), this is an example:

```
public partial class ControlName : UserControl
{
    public ControlName()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    public btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Suppose that I need to access to the property Foo of MainVM here
       //I need to access to MainWindow instance like this:
       Application.Current.MainWindow.mc.Foo

       //isn't possible instead access to the property directly inherit the class, like:
       MainVm.Foo 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific; in what part of the application do you need to use "Application.Current.MainWindow.mc.Foo" ? You dont need Application.Current if your code is in the controller, and I struggle to see where you need to acces the controller in the external application. If you could add a bit more code to your last part of the question please.

Comment: @PhillipH sure check the update

Comment: Hi. I guess you did not understand the idea behind MVVM. Please check this first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx, and try using a Framework or toolkit like http://www.mvvmlight.net/creating/

Comment: @Marco I already implemented the MVVM logic, I just asked how can I access to the property of a specific controller without passing by the MainWindow instance

Comment: Well, you are using btnAdd_Click which tells me it's still not MVVM. Anyway, inside the ControlName you could cast the DataContext back to the MainController or MainVM... which is bad, but it will work. I still recommend reading the docs i sent, the code you posted is not MVVM

Comment: @Marco suppose I have a Setting vm class where I store the application configuration, I need to read in the other vm the values of some property of the settings vm, you follow me? at this point I need to access to the instance mc to get the class instance of the settings vm. At this point could you provide an example that handle this situation? I'll be glad

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the configuration App-Wide, you could use the

```
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Whatever"];
```

These settings are located in the App.Config in the following form

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Whatever" value="Hello" />
</apSettings>
```

But as I undertand, you have a ViewModel that let Users change the settings, in this case you should go for:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
```

You ViewModel could expose this property as:

```
public Color MyColor
{
    get {
       return Properties.Settings.Default.myColor;
    }

    set {
        Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void Persist()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    // Raise whatever needed !
}
```

From other ViewModels you can access these setting as well:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor
```

Have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-application-settings

Comment: Ok, but suppose that the properties are filled by reading a json, I can access to the property value only using the settingsVm instance (name of the class which contains those settings), so I forced to call `Application.Current.MainWindow.mc.SettingsVm.PropertySettingsName`, you agree with me? there is no other way to do this

Comment: Nope. Properties.Settings.Default is available throughout all the application... you can call it  "global variables" if you wish. If you select user scope, the settings are saved in each user profile directory, more specifically, inside the AppData folder of the user profile in a file named user.config.
The full path is dependent of the application.
In Windows 7 it would be something like C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\[YourApp]
If you select app scope, C:\users\public\appdata\local

Comment: BTW, the file is xml. Like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <YourApp.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Whatever" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </YourApp.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: I know, but mine is just an example to explain the situation... Essentially the point of the question is: how to access to property of a specific view model class from another view model class without passing by MainWindow instance? Here I'm confused, hope in a reply, thanks for the time you invested so far :)

Comment: This one is easy ;-) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx - Use a Messenger

Comment: ... but don't overuse it